# GreenDao generator license issue

Tags: android, licensing, greendao, greendao-generator, commercial-application

I'm using greendao in a project and i like it but to be sure I checked the license another time. So I read [here](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/faq/), that the **generator** is licensed under the GPL v3.

Does that mean, the generated classes are also licensed under GPL v3 and therefore cannot be used in a commercial (closed source) app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fine to ship the generated classes with your app.

I just updated the FAQ to address this more clearly:
http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/faq/